# Finding a homotopy directly to show that two induced homomorphisms on a fundamental group are the same

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider the following problem:

“Let $I\in \pi_1(S^1,(1,0))$ be the class of the identity map. Show that $nI$ is the class of the map $f_n:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ given by $f_n(z)=z^n$.

I can solve it using the fact that $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb Z$. But without assuming this fact, how can one directly solve that problem only using the definition of homotopy? I tried to construct a homotopy writing paths in the polar coordinates but I couldn’t find any.

Comment: Assuming this is an introductory problem, I think the best place to start is to exhibit a homotopy between $f_1 * f_1$ and $f_2$.

Comment: Exactly I started with this case but I faced difficulty finding a homotopy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define loops in $X$ based at $x_0$ to be continuous maps $\gamma\colon[0,1] \to X$ with $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1) = x_0$.  This is equivalent to maps $f \colon S^1 \to X$ with $f(1,0) = x_0$, but it's a bit easier for me to think in terms of a real variable.

If $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are two loops, the usual definition of their concatenation $\gamma_1 * \gamma_2$ is
$$
    (\gamma_1 * \gamma_2)(t) = \begin{cases}
        \gamma_1(2t) & 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
        \gamma_2(2t-1) & \frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1
    \end{cases}
$$
The idea is that you split up the interval $[0,1]$ into two sub-intervals, you do $\gamma_1$ on the first half (scaling $[0,\frac12]$ to $[0,1]$), then $\gamma_2$ on the second half (scaling and shifting $[\tfrac12,1]$ to $[0,1]$).

But you can also break up the interval into unequal pieces $[0,z]$ and $[z,1]$.  You would get a weighted-concatenation operation
$$
    (\gamma_1 *_z \gamma_2)(t) = \begin{cases}
        \gamma_1\left(\frac{t}{z}\right) & 0 \leq t \leq z \\
        \gamma_2\left(\frac{t-z}{1-z}\right) & z \leq t \leq 1
    \end{cases}
$$
Notice that $\gamma_1 *_{1/2} \gamma_2 = \gamma_1 * \gamma_2$.  Also, all of the maps $\gamma_1 *_z \gamma_2$ are homotopic.  You just continuously move that breakpoint from one $z$-value to each other.  To be explicit:
$$
    h(t,s) = (\gamma_1 *_{s z_1 + (1-s)z_2} \gamma_2)(t)
$$
is a homotopy between $\gamma_1 *_{z_1} \gamma_2$ and $\gamma_1 *_{z_2} \gamma_2$.

Let $\eta_n \colon[0,1] \to S^1$ be the map $\eta_n(t) = e^{2\pi int}$.  Notice $\eta_n(t) = f_n(e^{2\pi i t})$, so they induce the same homotopy classes in $\pi_1(S^1)$.  Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers.  We want to show that $\eta_m * \eta_n$ is homotopic to $\eta_{m+n}$.

Now $\eta_{m+n}$ completes $m+n$ loops, equally spaced in the interval $[0,1]$.  $\eta_m * \eta_n$ also completes $m+n$ loops, but the first $m$ are equally spaced in the interval $[0,\frac12]$, and the last $n$ are equally spaced in the interval $[\frac12,1]$.  So let's form $\eta_m *_{m/(m+n)} \eta_n$ instead.  It completes its first $m$ loops equally spaced within the interval $[0,\frac{m}{m+n}]$, and its last $n$ loops equally spaced within the interval $[\frac{m}{m+n},1]$.  But this means that each loop is completed in the same width interval: $\frac{1}{m}\frac{m}{m+n} = \frac{1}{m+n}$ on the first part, and $\frac{1}{n}\left(1 - \frac{m}{m+n}\right) = \frac{1}{m+n}$ on the second part.  So in fact, $\eta_m *_{m/(n+m)} \eta_n = \eta_{n+m}$.  Since $\eta_m *_{m/(n+m)} \eta_n$ is homotopic to $\eta_m * \eta_n$, we are done.

Answer (score 2):

$S^1$ is a topological group under multiplication.

In general if $G$ is a topological group with identity $e$, then
there is an alternative multiplication on $\pi_1(G,e)$ given by
$[f]\cdot[g]=[h]$ where $h(t)=f(t)g(t)$ (multiplication in the group $G$).
The Hilton-Eckmann argument proves that this new multiplication
is the same as the standard group operation on $\pi_1(G,e)$ (and is
also commutative).

As a consequence, if $f$ is a loop from $e$ to $e$ in $G$, the
class of $n[f]$ in $\pi_1(G,e)$ is given by that of the path $t\mapsto
f(t)^n$. Your example is $G=S^1$, considered as a subgroup of $\Bbb C^*$.

Comment: Thanks. It is a polished solution but the problem is given right after introducing homotopy so the solution should  use only the definition of homotopy

Comment: What else does this use? Do you mean the definition of topological group?

Comment: @JustinYoung no, I haven’t seen the Hilton-Eckmann argument yet

Comment: It's a purely algebraic argument, and you don't have to cite it, you can prove it for yourself. Show that in a topological group, the two operations on $\pi_1$ agree and are both abelian. Hint: $G\times G \to G$ induces a homomorphism for the "standard" multiplication on $\pi_1$.